# Automatic job to delete bigquery table records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-dataflow

Is there a way to schedule deletion of rows from bigquery table based on a column condition? Something like a job to schedule to run every day.

For example, let's say I've a column called creation_date in the table. I need to delete records when creation_date is less than current date minus one week (`creation_date < current date - 7`). I need the job to run everyday on a specified time and delete records based on the creation date condition.

If there aren't any built in scheduler operations, could you suggest any options available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple simple options within BigQuery itself you can utilize.

The simplest is likely [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).  This will simply just execute a command on a schedule.  You can execute a `DELETE` statement or some other method.

Additionally you could set table or [partition expirations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#partition-expiration).  This one involves a little more legwork but would achieve a similar result.  Based on your description it would likely be a partition expiration you would want to set up.